# Java Split with 3 delimiters [ ] ,

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I want `Johann` as a result.

My code:

```
String rs = "[ Johann ,]";
String[] splitted = rs.split(","+"["+"]");
```

Comment: What content precisely should have your `splitted` array? Should it be array with only one element `Johann`? In that case you can'd do it with just `split`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following to remove all the special characters from string and filter out required output.

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s-]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) api of String like:

```
 String rs = "[Johann,]";
 System.out.println(rs.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,", ""));
 Output:
 Johann
```

Answer (score 0):

String.split expects a regular expression as argument. What about

```
String rs = "[ Johann ,]";
String[] splitted = rs.split("[,\\[\\]]");
```